# Date bucket search constraint based on a field

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am trying to build a bucketed constraint on a field index. When I run fn:count(cts:field-values()) the correct amount of values are returned, but when I try to perform a constrained search using the Search API, nothing happens.

The field configuration is set up on the following paths (can be either element name, should be treated equally):

mods:mods/mods:originInfo/mods:dateCreated[@keyDate] mods:mods/mods:originInfo/mods:dateIssued[@keyDate]

scalar type is gYear.

```
let $options :=
<search:options>
 <constraint name="date" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
   <range type="xs:gYear">
     <field name="date"/>
     <bucket name="any-1800" lt="1801">–1800</bucket>
     <bucket name="1801-1825" ge="1801" lt="1826">1801–1825</bucket>
     <bucket name="1826-1850" ge="1826" lt="1851">1826–1850</bucket>
     <bucket name="1851-1875" ge="1851" lt="1876">1851–1875</bucket>
     <bucket name="1876-1900" ge="1876" lt="1901">1876–1900</bucket>
     <bucket name="1901-1925" ge="1901" lt="1926">1901–1925</bucket>
     <bucket name="1926-1950" ge="1926" lt="1951">1926–1950</bucket>
     <bucket name="1951-1975" ge="1951" lt="1976">1951–1975</bucket>
     <bucket name="1976-2000" ge="1976" lt="2001">1976–2000</bucket>
     <bucket name="2001-any" ge="2001">2001–</bucket>
   </range>
 </constraint>
</search:options>
return search:search('"holy spirit" date: 1910', $options)
```

I am expecting search results to be returned that include the exact keyword phrase "holy spirit" that have the date: 1910. Instead I am just getting documents that match the keyword phrase regardless of date.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the blank after the colon, otherwise it is seen as a separate search term:

```
search:search('"holy spirit" AND date:1910', $options)
```

I added an AND to more explicit about things as well.

HTH!